# Sublists of Random Permutations

Tags: list-manipulation, random

What is an efficient way to create a list of (psudo)randomly chosen permutations?

I'm trying to create a list like below:

```
x = 5;
RandomChoice[Permutations[Range[1, x]], {x}]

{{1, 2, 4, 5, 3}, {5, 3, 1, 2, 4}, {5, 2, 3, 1, 4}, {1, 3, 2, 4, 5}, {3, 2, 4, 5, 1}}
```

However, this eats up a lot of memory and doesn't work after x=11.

Each sub-list does not necessarily have to be unique, but in this case it was.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the problem description you can simply shuffle the list as many times as needed, since duplicate permutations are allowed:

```
(* thanks ybeltukov for tweaks *)
f[n_, m_] := Table[RandomSample @ #, {m}] & @ Range @ n
```

Example:

```
f[5, 3]
```

> ```
> {{5, 3, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 4, 2, 5, 1}, {2, 1, 5, 3, 4}}
> ```

Comment: Even more efficient `f3[n_, m_] := Table[RandomSample@#, {m}] &@Range@n` :)

Answer (score 4):

`mrandomperms[n_, m_]:= Table[PermutationList[RandomPermutation[n]], {m}]`

Was my initial answer, but, as pointed out by Mr. Wizard, PermutationList should be given $n$ as a second argument, since otherwise it will give the wrong answer if $n$ is a fixed point. Also, Table can be eliminated for elegance and efficiency, leaving one with:

`mrandomperms[n_, m_]:= PermutationList[#, n]& /@ RandomPermutation[n, m]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Re second, true. Re first, PermutationList seems to work fine for me without the second arg (I checked before posting the answer), but now that I read the documentation I see that it is not guaranteed to work if the last element is a fixed point, so you are right.